# Organisation Pretending to be "Benevolent" in reality seeks to kill people who are helpful (The Organisation secretly hates these people)

Tags: single-word-requests

Let us say non-Chinese intelligence "Group Fox" goes to China and establishes an organisation say "HELP" whose overt **declared** aim is to "build a strong China".

Many Chinese people come forward and join this "HELP" organisation (thinking it is Chinese and will help China).

Unknown to these Chinese people their names and other details are handed over to other non-Chinese agencies by "HELP" through "Group Fox" and these Chinese people are then killed by non-Chinese intelligence agencies.

Questions:

What is the one word to describe the actions & activities  of "Group Fox" (*master mind* or *parent* organisation)?

What is the one word to describe the actions & activities of "HELP"  (*slave* or *child* organisation)?

Is there any such  word in English to describe this activity?

My suggestion

kindly do not suggest Agent Provocateur, because:

*Agent Provocateur* is the word used

- If it was a **single** person, but this is an organisation, so we can't use Agent Provocateur.
- Provocateur can be used only when people are duped into breaking the law. Here no law is broken

Hence what is the correct word?

Can we use the phrase 
"Wolf in sheep clothing".

Is there any similar phrase for a Corporate, Institution, Nation that performs such an action?

Comment: "False flag" is an adjective often applied to operations which claim to be one thing but are in fact much the opposite.  The term is applied to a wide variety of situations.

Answer (score 1):

These four BOLDED words are existing words. PARENT organization would be considered a "**subversive**" organization. CHILD organization would be considered to be a "**subsidiary**" established as a "**front**" for the PARENT organization. This ACTIVITY would be "**clandestine**" in nature. I did not understand your final "*suggestion - as a guide*" offering, so it had to be ignored.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/subversive

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/subsidiary

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/front

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/clandestine

Comment: Thank You,   but subversive is for a range of activities and does not evoke an image of this particular activity alone in a person's mind. Hence when we use the word subversive it could be any number of activities. Hence it seems generic to me. I am looking for a specific word limited to this activity alone. If that were possible or to create word to describe this activity.